Привязанные элементы к списку подтягиваются не сразу

У меня есть такие поля.
При заходе на страницу у меня по умолчанию выбрано в сущностях "Company", но если я хочу выбрать связанные с ним сущности, то они просто не выпадают при выборе этого списка,
но если я пощелкаю другие сущности, а потом опять выберу Company, то к нему уже подтянутся связанные с ним сущности, в чем может быть причина этой проблемы?
Код кейса Company:
$entity = Model::findClassById($model ? $model->entity : $entity_id);
    switch ($entity->className) {
        case Company::class:
            if (Yii::$app->user->getIsSuperAdmin()) {
                $returnData = Yii::$app->companyRepository->getAllCompaniesForSelectBox();

                break;
            }
            $returnData = Yii::$app->companyRepository->getCompaniesByMemberForSelectBox(Yii::$app->user->id);

            break;


Связанные списки можно реализовать с помощью виджета Select2 (https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-widget-select2)

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
